# Load .RData from an R script in Scala using Renjin

Tags: r, scala, renjin

I have an R script `load.R` that attempts to do

```
load("test.RData")
```

When I run:

```
engine.eval(new FileReader("load.R"))
```

An exception occurs:

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/tukaani/xz/XZInputStream
    at org.renjin.primitives.io.connections.Connections.gzfile(Connections.java:79)
    at org.renjin.primitives.R$primitive$gzfile.doApply(R$primitive$gzfile.java:75)
    at org.renjin.primitives.R$primitive$gzfile.apply(R$primitive$gzfile.java:36)
    at org.renjin.primitives.special.InternalFunction.apply(InternalFunction.java:45)
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluateCall(Context.java:302)
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:222)
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:163)
    at org.renjin.sexp.Closure.doApply(Closure.java:83)
    at org.renjin.eval.ClosureDispatcher.apply(ClosureDispatcher.java:73)
    at org.renjin.eval.ClosureDispatcher.applyClosure(ClosureDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.renjin.sexp.Closure.apply(Closure.java:78)
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluateCall(Context.java:302)
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:222)
    at org.renjin.primitives.special.AssignLeftFunction.assignLeft(AssignLeftFunction.java:57)
    at org.renjin.primitives.special.AssignLeftFunction.apply(AssignLeftFunction.java:41)
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluateCall(Context.java:302)
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:222)
    at org.renjin.primitives.special.BeginFunction.apply(BeginFunction.java:38)
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluateCall(Context.java:302)
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:222)
    at org.renjin.primitives.special.IfFunction.apply(IfFunction.java:40)
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluateCall(Context.java:302)
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:222)
    at org.renjin.primitives.special.BeginFunction.apply(BeginFunction.java:38)
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluateCall(Context.java:302)
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:222)
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:163)
    at org.renjin.sexp.Closure.doApply(Closure.java:83)
    at org.renjin.eval.ClosureDispatcher.apply(ClosureDispatcher.java:73)
    at org.renjin.eval.ClosureDispatcher.applyClosure(ClosureDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.renjin.sexp.Closure.apply(Closure.java:78)
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluateCall(Context.java:302)
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:222)
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluateExpressionVector(Context.java:285)
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:220)
    at org.renjin.script.RenjinScriptEngine.eval(RenjinScriptEngine.java:145)
    at org.renjin.script.RenjinScriptEngine.eval(RenjinScriptEngine.java:104)
    at com.infosistema.imp.restservice.data_treatment.DataTreatment.<init>(DataTreatment.scala:34)
    at com.infosistema.imp.restservice.data_treatment.Main$.<init>(DataTreatment.scala:45)
    at com.infosistema.imp.restservice.data_treatment.Main$.<clinit>(DataTreatment.scala)
    at com.infosistema.imp.restservice.data_treatment.Main.main(DataTreatment.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.tukaani.xz.XZInputStream
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 46 more
```

I don't know R. I'm merely attempting to use R code to process some data in a Java/Scala application using Renjin.

Reading the data section on the [documention](http://docs.renjin.org/en/latest/library/moving-data-between-java-and-r-code.html) nothing is said about loading data from `.RData` files.

**UPDATED:**
In my `build.sbt` file I have:

```
resolvers += "BeDataDriven" at https://nexus.bedatadriven.com/content/groups/public",
libraryDependencies += "org.renjin" % "renjin-script-engine" % "0.8.1886"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was `coursier` not being able to resolve all dependencies (without any notice).

Removing `addSbtPlugin("io.get-coursier" % "sbt-coursier" % "1.0.0-M15")` from `plugins.sbt` and using sbt's default resolver fixed the issue.

Comment: Phew! Glad you were able to resolve the problem! Was coursier's problem specifically with Renjin or another dependency?

Comment: Apparently it just couldn't resolve `org.tukaani:xz`. Was using coursier for over a month and that was the first time it "failed". Still trying to figure out why...

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce this so we can submit a bug report to coursier but my super simple project seems to work: https://github.com/bedatadriven/renjin-sbt-example/tree/coursier What version of scala are you using?

Comment: 2.11.8. I subnutted an issue but havent bothered to create a minimal working example yet.

Answer (score 1):

It is not enough to just have renjin-script-engine.jar on your classpath, you need its dependencies as well.

If you are using SBT to build your Scala project, then you need to add the following to your build file:

```
resolvers +=
  "BeDataDriven" at "https://nexus.bedatadriven.com/content/groups/public"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    name := "renjin-test",
    version := "1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.10.6",
    libraryDependencies += "org.renjin" % "renjin-script-engine" % "0.8.1886"
)
```

For other build tools, see:
http://docs.renjin.org/en/latest/library/project-setup.html

Comment: I do have that dependency and the repository in my `build.sbt`. I read the documentation from top to point 4 more than once. Plus that doesn't make much sense since when I put a .jar in the classpath I never have to worry about it's dependencies, otherwise each project would have hundreds of non direct dependencies. It's up to the build system to figure out your dependencie's dependencies.

Comment: Nonetheless - something is wrong with your classpath because org.tukaani.xz.XZInputStream is not on it. This class is in the org.tukaani:xz:1.0 artifact, and normally should appear as xz-1.0.jar on your classpath. Double check the actually command line to the JVM to find out where it's going wrong!

Comment: I agree that it isn't in the classpath (and I checked). But according to the renjin docs I don't need anymore dependencies other than:  `"org.renjin" % "renjin-script-engine" % "0.8.1886"`

Comment: Can you run the application directly from sbt? You can add the line mainClass := Some("com.infosistema.imp.restservice.data_treatment.Main") to your build file and then execute "sbt run". If this runs without error then it's likely a problem with IntelliJ.